# Cant access a property in a returned JSON object

Tags: c#, json

This json is really odd to me and I cannot access the property inside it (`StudentId` and `CourseId`). I'm not the one who designed it.

How can I access them properly with C#?

```
{
  "Result": [
    "Done",
    {
      "StudentId": 45,
      "CourseId": 27
    }
  ]
}
```

I also tried to check [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) but I just get this result:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thats standard JSON, nothing unusual

Comment: A little off-topic: imho, this is an ugly JSON object. `Result` is an array of objects which can either be objects or strings (or idk maybe something else). `Result` does not representate something clear, it would be better if it was an array of objects having `Status = Done` and `Data = { StudentId: ..., CourseId: ... }`. However, it is still **valid and deserializable**.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I see, thanks. How can I access them?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev That isn't awful JSON at all?

Comment: @ipid not too sure as i dont really know C#, sorry

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks for the info. How can I access the property with C#?

Comment: How can you access the properties using object type, try a statically typed class and it would work

Comment: One recent solution to a similar problem: [Parse universities from VK API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940231/3744182)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, surely a poor Json, which makes little sense object / business wise, just a valid Json

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it isn't a poor JSON?? that is a valid json dataset which is laid out how it should be

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it is clear what result is if you read it, i don't see why everyone says this is a bad JSON dataset when it really isn't

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Because it is inconsistent and inconvenient to work with, especially in strongly-typed languages. A developer who works with it should know that "there is an array, and the first item is string and contains status, and the second one is an object and contains data". Just think: **it is an array which length is known at design-time; array contains objects of different types; and expected type can be acquired by item's index in the given array** - it is definitely poor.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it really isnt... my job revolves around sorting JSON from api calls...

Answer (score 0):

You may define your list items as `dynamic`:

```
 public class RootObject
 {
     public List<dynamic> Result { get; set; }
 }
```

Then access the desired properties directly. But in this case you have to check if they exist yourself (using `try...catch` for example):

```
var json = @"{
    ""Result"": [
    ""Done"",
    {
        ""StudentId"": 45,
        ""CourseId"": 27
    }
    ]
}";

var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (var res in rootObject.Result)
    if (res is string)
        Console.WriteLine(rootObject.Result[0]);
    else
        try
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(res.StudentId);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Unexpected element type
        }
```